# How to capture type of html input

Tags: php, forms

When i use "print_r($_POST)" it just captured "name" of input. 
How to get parameter input, such as "type" or "name" from html form :

```
<form method="post">Nama : <input type="text" name="nama" /><br />
Jabatan : <input type="hidden" name="id_jabatan" value="2"><br>
Kontak : <input type="text" name="kontak"><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br>
UserID : <input type="text" name="userid"><br>
Foto : <input type="file" name="foto"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Simpan" name="simpan">
</form>
```

I filled up that form with this values :
AA
2
W
CC
dD
Simpan

This is result of "print_r($_POST)" :

```
Array
(
    [nama] => AA
    [id_jabatan] => 2
    [kontak] => VV
    [email] => CC
    [userid] => dD
    [foto] => 
    [simpan] => Simpan
)
```

just name of input captured
Please help :)

Comment: things which are stored in session array can be shown as output on screen

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi oh yeah.. but, how to get type of input ?

Comment: Did you search on google?

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes i did, but most of result describe about "name", not about "type"

Comment: Well as far as i see theres no possible solution of it out there. Let me try some.

Comment: Well as far as i see, its not possible using PHP. But you can achieve this using jQuery. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes, thankyou william, how to do that with jQuery ?

Comment: May i ask ,why do you need to know the "type" attribute?

Comment: @boomcruiser i need to build some class or function that can easily for writing $_POST code

Comment: guess - Could you load the HTML into the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) then using the `name` from the  `$_POST` array to locate that item in the `DOM` and extract the required information that way?

Comment: @RyanVincent, i think its good i idea.. let me try

Comment: @RyanVincent, i tried PHP SImple HTML DOM, but how to make POST with that ?.. that great class for capturing string only

Comment: @andibastian — How will knowing the type of control used to generate the form data help you right that class? What do you plan to use the information for?

Comment: I am using the instructions found: [Top 10 Best Usage Examples of PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://nimishprabhu.com/top-10-best-usage-examples-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html). And: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_create)

Comment: thankyou ryan @RyanVincent, i will try again, i'll inform you

Answer (score 0):

Any piece of information from the session array is available using the following function:
$this->session->userdata('item');

Where item is the array index corresponding to the item you wish to fetch. For example, to fetch the session ID you will do this:
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');

Note: The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are trying to access does not exist.
try something like this

```
$sessiondata = array(
                                  'username' => $username,
                                  'password'=>$password,
                                  'email'=>$email,
                                  'is_login' => TRUE
                             );
                             //$this->login_model->set_session($username);
                             $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
                             print_r($this->session->all_userdata());  //to check
```

Comment: I dont think you understood his problem bro.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example demonstrating the use of [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

It demonstrates accessing the 'type' and 'value' of the input fields.

```
<?php

include __DIR__ .'/vendor/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php';

// restrict the list of names to use
$inputNames = array("nama", "kontak", "email", "userid", "foto", "id_jabatan", "simpan");

if (empty($_POST)) { // supply default values
    $_POST = array();
    foreach ($inputNames as $name) {
        $_POST[$name] = '';
    }
}


$html = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form action="" method="post">
          Nama : <input type="text" name="nama" value="{$_POST['nama']}" ><br />
          Kontak : <input type="text" name="kontak" value="{$_POST['kontak']}"><br />
          Email : <input type="text" name="email" value="{$_POST['email']}"><br />
          UserID : <input type="text" name="userid" value="{$_POST['userid']}"><br />
          Foto : <input type="file" name="foto" value="{$_POST['foto']}"><br />
          <input type="hidden" name="id_jabatan" value="2"><br>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Simpan" name="simpan">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
EOF;

// parse the HTML and the POST inputs.
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $htmlDom = str_get_html($html);

    // find all the elements with a name
    $elements = $htmlDom->find('[name]');
    foreach ($elements as $node) {
        if (!in_array($node->attr['name'], $inputNames)) {
            continue; // ignore
        }

        echo 'The Name is: ', $node->attr['name'], ' ',
             'The Tag/Type is: ', $node->tag, ' ', ' / ',  $node->attr['type'], ' ',
             'The Value is: ', $node->attr['value'], '<br />';

    }
}

// show the form with the current values.
echo '<br />';
echo $html;

exit;
```

Output:

```
The Name is: nama The Tag/Type is: input / text The Value is:
The Name is: kontak The Tag/Type is: input / text The Value is:
The Name is: email The Tag/Type is: input / text The Value is: xxx@ttt
The Name is: userid The Tag/Type is: input / text The Value is:
The Name is: foto The Tag/Type is: input / file The Value is: Winter.jpg
The Name is: id_jabatan The Tag/Type is: input / hidden The Value is: 2
The Name is: simpan The Tag/Type is: input / submit The Value is: Simpan


Nama :
Kontak :
Email :
UserID :
Foto :
```